# Adjust FCM algorithm with size constrains

Tags: algorithms, data-mining, cluster

I want to cluster a list of property addressed based on distance and limit the size of each cluster.

The properties are currently assigned to modules by discretion of managers. But I hope to develop a system to assign properties automatically based on minimized distance to module center and limit the size of properties and units in each cluster.

The number of clusters are predefined.

I found this article with the algorithm I'm looking for.

[Clustering with Size Constraints](https://public.fh-wolfenbuettel.de/~klawonn/Papers/hoeppnerklawonn08.pdf)

Please bear with me since I new to clustering and algorithm design. I get the idea of the algorithm in the article. But since I have very basic math and programming background, there're some details I'm not quite clear about.

So for the equation (4) in FCM Algorithm part, I don't understand what it means..
[image]

And for equation (8), I don't understand how it's obtained and what it's referring to in the description.

[image]

If anyone can help me with any of these, I'd much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Raphael I hope I wasn't out of line [recommending to post this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546239/how-to-adjust-fcm-algorithm-with-size-constrains-by-coding?noredirect=1#comment47277740_29546239); I figured that adjusting that algorithm should require adjusting the proof of correctness, so I figured it should go here.

Comment: I think I have the algorithm I want, but I don't know how to implement it by programming. Any suggestions on what language to start with or code I could reference would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @G.Bach Adjusting algorithms is fine here, but implementing them for practical use is (usually) not. It seems qshngv wants the latter.

Comment: Hi @Raphael, thanks for the clarification. I do have some questions about the algorithm, I've edited my post accordingly. Could you take another look please?

Comment: And thanks @G. Bach again for the information.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!